# Call Method with parameters in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, methods, parameters, appdelegate

OK, so I have my CoreLocation stuff up and running in my AppDelegate, and have some methods using that.
Now, I want to call one of these methods in the AppDelegate from my ViewController. The parameters necessary for this method however [i.e. location stuff], are not known to my ViewController.
Should I now setup that whole CoreLocation hoopla in my ViewController, or is there an easier, smarter and more elegant way for this?
(I'm very afraid that this question shows that I kind of miss the fundamentals of programming, but I'm willing to make a fool out of myself)
Thanks for bothering...

Example: In my AppDelegate, there is a method called

```
-(void) sendDataToServer:(CLLocation *)newLocation
```

It needs a location as an input. The CoreLocation is initialised in the AppDelegate, and therefore the location parameters are known in the APpDelegate. But NOT in the ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acces the AppDelegate with: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`

Comment: OK, but how would I pass parameters to a method in the AppDelegate, that are only known to the AppDelegate?

Comment: Like with any other class

Comment: I have edited my question, to make my problem a bit more clear, hopefully.

Comment: Call other method in AppDelegate where you have acces to _newLocation_ and in that method call _sendDataToServer:_